# Shutting down audio in a particular website

Tags: javascript, audio

I tried to use the following `mutationObserver` to observe for all `audio` tags to remove them so to totally shut down sound in a particular website. I ran the script with Greasemonkey.

```
new MutationObserver(() => {
    document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach(node=>node.remove())
}).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

This wasn't enough, because some `audio` tags are loaded before the `DOMContentLoaded`.

What could I do to remove these audio tags as well (i.e, those loaded before being catched by the `mutationObserver`)?

I though of using `setInterval()` each 1 millisecond but this seems to me as something I really need to avoid as it would feel my PC's memory and stuck the browser.

<sub>Let me emphasize: It's just a script I ran on whatever website, so there is no HTML or CSS to show in this question.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all audio is done with `<audio>` tags.  Audio can come from media elements not attached to the DOM.  It can also be produced with the Web Audio API, perhaps even in conjunction with the MediaDevice API.  Audio can also be produced by plugins.

You will need to write a browser extension and use the API for the particular browser you're extending to mute the tab.

Comment: What is "controllable" by JS, from all the implementations you have namedropped (besides `audio` tags), dear Brad?

Comment: All of it, except plugins.  Many plugins can also be controlled, but you'd have to write code for each one individually.

Comment: Brad, `setInterval(
    ()=>{ document.querySelector('audio').forEach((e)=>{
        e.remove();
    });
}, 1000);`
could most certainly help with `audio` tags but what about the **Web audio API** and **MediaDevice API** you mentioned? Can I totally shut any sound of theirs with `setInterval()` as well?

Comment: @Arcticooling No, you could try hooking into these APIs and overriding portions of them but you're going to have to guarantee your code loads before anything else.  Why not just use the browser extension API and mute the tab?

Comment: You mean to click on the speaker icon on the relevant tab of the website to shut it's sound? Well, I don't want to do that repeatedly as sometimes the sound just comes up when the volume is high and it jumps me up (panic-like reflex response). Given that I just want to arbitrarily mute these. I really need an anutomatic solution for the two APIs you mentioned and I'll most appreciate any take on this, in great plea.

Comment: Oh, sadly I don't see that happening sometime soon because I have no idea even where to start. Perhaps in the future I'll have that knowledge...

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for browser extensions. It's going to be like 3 lines of code. Way easier than what you're proposing.

Comment: Hmm, reading about how to create a browser extenstion in general, and then, reading about how to create a browser extension that 1. Disables all audio. 2. Work in a specific website. Is that correct?

Comment: @Arcticooling You can have it work on a specific site, or apply to all tabs.